# explaining a recurrent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let a>2 .

> $\phi=a- \frac{1}{a- \frac{1}{a-\frac{1}{a-\frac{1}{....}}}}$
>
> $\phi_0=a$ and $\phi_{n+1}=a-\frac{1}{\phi_n}$

How to explain the relation between   $\phi_0, \phi_1,  \phi_3$  series and    $\phi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi=a-\dfrac{1}{\phi}$, then we have $$\phi_2=a-\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1}{\phi}},$$

$$\phi_3=a-\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1}{\phi}}},$$ etc.

We can get $\phi$ from $\phi=a-\dfrac{1}{\phi}$, i.e. $$\phi^2-a\phi+1=0.$$

We have

$$\phi_{1,2}=\dfrac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}.$$

Comment: It is $\phi = a-\frac{1}{\phi}$ true, but $$\phi=a-\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1}{a}}}$$ is not true. But this is the idea. Actually, $$\phi_3=a-\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1}{a}}}$$

Comment: Yes, I forget to give the index number. We find $\phi_n$ with $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

This continue fraction is infinity. Thus $lim \phi_n\to \phi$. Note that $\phi=a-\frac{1}{\phi}$. You can find the roots of $ \phi^2- a \phi +1=0$ to find $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi$ has any meaning at all, it is the limit of the sequence $\phi_n$.  The challenge is to prove that the limit exists if $a > 2$.